# Cloud Functions for Firebase - event.data read special value

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently learning to use cloud functions from firebase and just have the following problem:

In my database the structure I´ll be referring to looks like that:

- fruits

  - RandomFruitID

    - fruitID: RandomFruitID

In my index.js I want to create the function:

```
    exports.newFruit = functions.database.ref("fruits").onWrite(event => {
    (...)

    // INSIDE HERE I WANT TO ACCESS THE "fruitID" VALUE, MEANING THE "RandomFruitID"
    });
```

How can I achieve that?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function will trigger on any change under `/fruits`. So there is no **current** fruitID value.

If you want to trigger when a specific fruit gets written, you'll want to change the trigger to `fruits/{fruidId}`. This also makes the value of `fruitId` available in your code:

```
exports.newFruit = functions.database.ref("fruits/{fruitId}").onWrite(event => {
  if (!event.data.previous.exists()) {
    var newFruitKey = event.params.fruitId;
    ...
  }
});
```

I recommend reading the [Firebase documentation for Database triggered functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value), which covers a lot of such cases.